# setFont() Applying Everything except Size Changes

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I am trying to apply Class-Based Font changes, and have found this information: [Changing font size of all QLabel objects PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63442415/changing-font-size-of-all-qlabel-objects-pyqt5)

```
QFont font_label = QFont("MS Shell Dlg 2", 12, QFont::Normal);
QApplication::setFont(font_label, "QLabel");
```

The above code successfully applies everything except the Font Size, and calling `font_label.setPointSize(x);` does not change anything.

**Project Details:**

- Using Qt 5.12.11 with CMake and MSVC
- **Creating .ui files with QT Designer**
- Besides implementing QDarkStlyeSheet I do nothing relevant with Style Sheets
- No other Font alterations appear in my code

**I have also discovered odd reproducible examples:**

- I thought it had to do with my QLabels being RichText, but changing them all to PlainText did not solve anything.
- **The only QLabel's that resize are default pointSize ones**
- My layouts do not seems to be imposing anything that would limit their size changes, and the above situations seems to support this.
- This problem occurs when trying to change the font size in any direction.

**UI File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MreApp</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MreApp">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1920</width>
    <height>1050</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MreApp</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="Back">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_1">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>490</x>
      <y>660</y>
      <width>95</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>8</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>I start size 8</string>
    </property>
    <property name="textFormat">
     <enum>Qt::PlainText</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>690</x>
      <y>80</y>
      <width>481</width>
      <height>131</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Try Draggin in a new QLabel in QT Designer, it will listen to the code temporarily.</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>660</x>
      <y>570</y>
      <width>95</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>I start size 10</string>
    </property>
    <property name="textFormat">
     <enum>Qt::PlainText</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>780</x>
      <y>570</y>
      <width>95</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>I start size 10</string>
    </property>
    <property name="textFormat">
     <enum>Qt::PlainText</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>1190</x>
      <y>570</y>
      <width>371</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>(The Label Below is a fresh one, dragged in from QT Designer)</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>1270</x>
      <y>690</y>
      <width>201</width>
      <height>61</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>TextLabel</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <action name="menu_new">
   <property name="text">
    <string>New</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="menu_load">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Load</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="menu_save">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Save</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="menu_saveAs">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Save As</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="menu_userManual">
   <property name="text">
    <string>User Manual</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: If you want to *actually* reset a value in the property editor, you should not manually set that value, but press the red "undo" arrow for that property. That said, you have to provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante I have set up a MRE in the most convenient fashion I could think of.

Comment: Sorry, but questions should always be self-contained, and cannot use external resources that be unavailable to some users or can be deleted in the future. Please try to include all necessary code inside the question.

Comment: It's very important to use [QFontInfo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontinfo.html) when debugging font issues, because that is the only reliable way to know the true font properties being used (rather than what was merely *requested* via `QFont`). In this particular case, "MS Shell Dlg 2" is a *logical font*, so the specific font family that it maps to, as well as the available point-sizes, can differ greatly between systems (e.g. depending on the locale).

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for the guidance, I have changed the MRE and discovered more

Comment: @AlexanderAlexander How would this update actually provide more help? You just added the code to create an almost empty application, there's no trace of your usage of the dark style, and the UI is not included, so we don't know what you actually *did* change there nor you explained what should we do in order to actually reproduce the problem, you just gave us a list of issues. Besides UI files are plain simple XML files.

Comment: @musicamante As stated above, I cut off all .qrc resources and still reproduced the issue, thus the update displays that dark style is both innocent and irrelevant. My apologies about the .ui file, my new simplified one is small enough to post now, unlike the original one. Also, the application is "almost empty' because the issue is simple enough to reproduce. My "list of issues" is just scenarios in which the main issue presents itself.

Comment: I'm really not sure I understand the problem but you appear to be using stylesheets in conjunction with `QApplication::setFont`.  The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#setFont) explicitly states: `Warning: Do not use this function in conjunction with Qt Style Sheets`.

Comment: @G.M. I have cut out all stylesheets and .qrc resources but the issue persists. I have actually read that disclaimer but have seen other people using the function in conjunction with non-widget-specific sheets. To clarify the issue: under no circumstance, except a QLabel's default pointSize, can I have a QLabel resize itself with ```setFont()```.

Comment: @AlexanderAlexander so: 1. It all resolves to my very first comment, using or resetting the *actual* default value in Designer; 2. The problem was that you *explicitly* specified a different font size in Designer, but expected that using `QApplication.setFont` would override that, which doesn't make a lot of sense: the docs [***clearly*** say](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#setFont) that it "Changes the **default** application font", if you override the font size of a widget in designer, changing the ***default*** font won't do *anything* for that widget!!!

Comment: @musicamante My clear misunderstanding of ```QApplication.setFont()```, QT Designer technicalities, and Default Fonts should of been immediately addressed then, as seen with Mat's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set a fixed font size for the `QLabels` in the `ui` therefore when you change the application's global font size, it won't affect those.

```
<font>
  <pointsize>10</pointsize>
 </font>
```

Changing the application's font size sets a default size for the widgets. If you set the font size of one specific widget, it will overwrite the default one (this is what happened in your case).

If you want to change the font size, set the widget's font, like:

```
auto lbl = ui->label_2;
auto font = lbl->font();
font.setPointSize(2);
lbl->setFont(font);
```

Comment: I had no idea that this was the case. What would be the best way to tackle entire classes then? In my implementation I need to resize many things at once, and rely on the QT Designer for rapid UI development.

Comment: If you reset the `QLabel` specific pointsizes in the Designer (or just remove them from the ui file) , your solution will work. Or if you just want to change the size:
  `auto font = QApplication::font("QLabel");
  font.setPointSize(11);
  QApplication::setFont(font, "QLabel");`.

+ the `return;` in your `scaling()` is not necessary

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The first half of what you said works, but the second half still doesn't do anything. Would there be any way to use ``` QApplication::setFont(font, "QLabel") ``` without resetting all the pointsizes in Designer? If that's the only way then I guess its the only real solution to the problem.

Comment: @AlexanderAlexander it seems like you're still missing the point: `setFont` sets a **default** font, if you explicitly change the font properties in Designer, those properties of the default font will be *ignored*, since you're overriding them. The real question, then, is: if you want to specify a default font size for labels, why do you want to override it in Designer (or, why don't you want to reset them)?

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I now see that this was all a simple overlooked misunderstanding. I never realized that you are overtly overriding the default font properties when making changes in Designer, and that ```QApplication.setFont``` would not change anything due to it only affecting default values. I will leave this question up for new developers that might fall into the same conundrum.

Comment: @AlexanderAlexander nobody's perfect ;-) I suggest you to take your time and *simplify* your question (you can remove the C++ part, as the only important aspect is setFont) and clarify with the basic steps and aspects of your original doubt (which were many, but as you now probably realize, also were only indirect symptoms of a simple problem). This will help others easily understand if your problem/misconception is also theirs, and will make understanding much easier to them.